# How to do faceting with sub-facet and aggregate functions using PySolr

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

I have a facet query working with count but I would like to do a sum on a field on the data already grouped by the facet.field. I have the json facet query working in the browser but no luck with PySolr.

```
import pysolr
import pprint

conn = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8080/solr/corename')
result = conn.search('*:*', **{
    'facet': 'true',
    'facet.type': 'terms',
    'facet.limit': 5,
    'facet.field': 'field_name',
    'f.results.facet.sum': '{!func}sum(daily_amount)'
})   

pprint.pprint(result.facets)
```

I would like to do a sum on a particualr field, is that possible in PySolr?

Comment: Have you seen the JSON Facet API? It allows you to create buckets and operations on those buckets: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement as listed under Sorting Facets By Nested Functions
on the link above, I have it working via CURL, how can I achieve the same in PySolr?

Comment: See https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr/issues/213 for an example: `'json.facet': json.dumps({'uniq':"unique(foo)"}),`

Comment: Tried that earlier but finally got it working now, thanks.

Comment: Add a proper, contained example as an answer and accept it yourself so that future search engine users find out how to do it properly right here :-)